# Bash script to filter or list the Azure storage blob files for last 30 days

Tags: bash, azure, shell

```sh
Blob_var=$(az storage blob list \
  --account-name devopsmisctaskhachprod \
  --container-name prod-servicebus-backup \
  --account-key fasfnacklasaasasascbvkevz= \
  --query "[].{name:name, created:properties.creationTime}" )
echo "$Blob_var"
```

This is the command to list all the blob files for the azure storage with dates.
I need to list blob files and filter them according to the last 30 days.
I am not getting any command to do so to extract the blob files according to the last created date or last modified date. Would you all please help me with this?

Comment: need a bash command to filter out .json files which are older than 30 days from Azure blob storage list. I all ready have that script in PowerShell but I need to have it in shell or bash.

Answer (score 1):

Please try something like:

```
Blob_var=$(az storage blob list --account-name devopsmisctaskhachprod --container-name prod-servicebus-backup --account-key fasfnacklasaasasascbvkevz= --query "[?properties.creationTime>='2021-02-26T00:00:00Z'].{name:name, created:properties.creationTime}") 
echo "$Blob_var"
```

You can read more about filtering arrays here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/query-azure-cli#filter-arrays.

Comment: need a bash command to filter out .json files which are older than 30 days. I all ready have that script in PowerShell but I need to have it in shell or bash.

Comment: Did you see my answer espcially `?properties.creationTime>='2021-02-26T00:00:00Z` part? This is how you would filter the data.